# Magento sales_order_place_before $observer getevent null

Tags: php, magento

i have the following observer method:

```
public function ModifyOrderECC(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    //sales_order_place_before
    Mage::log('ECC!! = ModifyOrderECC has been called successfully - event/array-5', null, 'mylog.log');
    $cart = $observer->getEvent()->getCart();
    try{
        if($cart != NULL)
        {
            Mage::log('$cart contains data!', null, 'mylog.log');

            foreach ($cart->getItems() as $item) {
                $getID = $item->getProduct()->getId();
                $productName = $item->getProduct()->getName();
                $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
                $quantity = (string)$item->getProduct()->getQtyOrdered();

                Mage::log('ID: '.$getID, null, 'mylog.log');
                Mage::log('Name: '.$productName, null, 'mylog.log');
                Mage::log('Price: '.$productPrice, null, 'mylog.log');
                Mage::log('Qty: '.$quantity, null, 'mylog.log');
            }
        }else
        {
            Mage::log('sorry Cart is null :(', null, 'mylog.log');
        }

    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        Mage::log('error = '.$e->getMessage(), null, 'mylog.log');
    }

}
```

however the getCart event is null, and I've also tried getquote which is also null. I need to get the contents of the cart from the event to see what contents its creating.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per as, ***sales_order_place_before*** event it ***only provide Order object and enable to provide quote object directly***.

You want `quote object` from this event then you need to get `quote id` from `Order object` then  using  `quote id you can get quote object`.

```
 public function ModifyOrderECC(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //sales_order_place_before


        $QuoteID=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getQuoteId();
    $quoteObject=Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($QuoteID);
...
    }
```

Comment: in the $observer you have only the order, getQuoteId will return null

Comment: there are some mistake .. Now answer is update ..please check now

Answer (score 1):

This event gives you an entire `order` instance instead of a `cart` one as you can see by looking in the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class (line 1113).

If you want to retrieve the `cart` then do:

```php
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I know i can retrieve the cart, what i want to do is check the event object is also the same, then make amendments to it.